# Find the value of $\int_1^4 xf''(x)dx$ when $f(1) = 2$, $f(4) = 7$, $f'(1) = 5$, $f'(4) = 3$, and $f''$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Find the value of $\int_1^4 xf''(x)dx$ when $f(1) = 2$, $f(4) = 7$, $f'(1) = 5$, $f'(4) = 3$, and $f''$ is continuous.

I'd like to see a full solution please!

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Hint: use integration by parts.

Comment: I attempted integration by parts but failed. I wasn't sure if this was the correct approach or not. I appreciate the hint @Galc127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may just integrate by parts:
$$
\int_1^4 xf''(x)dx=\left.xf'(x)\right|_1^4-\int_1^4 f'(x)dx=4\times f'(4)-\left.f(x)\right|_1^4.
$$